# Purpose of sampling in VAE

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, autoencoder

I am trying out a basic architecture of Variational Autoencoder(VAE) in my project. But this generative model is not used for images, but for words. I came across a term called "Sampling from the normal distribution". What does this sampling mean? What is the purpose of it?

Answer (score 0):

Normal distribution is a continuous probability distribution.

Sampling from normal distribution means getting a discrete value(or a set of discrete values) out of this equation.

This sampling is generally achieved by simple algorithms like Box-Muller Transform. Numpy and CUDA has facilities that can generate N values from a given normal distribution.

Comment: is the distribution always normal? In what cases do these distribution changes?